# Calling Thread.sleep() inside an asychronous method

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, asynchronous, sleep

Is it possible to test if an asynchronous (EJB @Asynchronous) method is really working as asynchronous by calling, for example, Thread.sleep(4000) inside that particular method to see if the sleep actually stops the other web client processes for 4 seconds or if the process just happens within the asynchronous method and the client itself would move on to next tasks?

I'm asking because, if the sleep(4000) call would stop the webclient from operating for 4 seconds even if the Asynchronous method works as intended, I would be getting failed test results even though my code is working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` only pauses the one thread that calls the method - all other methods continue executing normally. The whole idea of asynchronous execution is that you have multiple threads that can run independently, so if one takes a while it doesn't affect the others.

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed. So my @Asynchronous method isn't really working as it should at the moment. Sigh. Thanks for the answer anyway.